# Check if a primary key exists

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, explode

I think this has already been asked, but none of the answers made sense to me. My code is...

```
if ($current_string == "") {

    $new_entry_query = 'INSERT INTO house (id, string) VALUES ("' . $userid . '", "' . $new_home_entry . '")';
    mysql_query($new_entry_query);
    Header('Location: landing.php?pho=');

} else {

    $entry_update_string = $current_string . $new_home_entry;
    $new_entry_query = 'UPDATE house SET string="' . $entry_update_string . '" WHERE id="' . $userid . '";';
    mysql_query($new_entry_query);
    Header('Location: landing.php?pho=');

}
```

My table has two columns. "id", which is primary, and "string" which is not. If you notice, in the first if-statement I'm checking if the query for "string" came up empty, when I asked the database to check at my "id."

I've run into a problem. There is another function on my site which deletes everything from the "string" column. If that function runs, then I run this script I will end up getting an error.

I need to check if the "id" is already there, so that I know if I should create an entirely new row, or just append "string." How would I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You should use one query:

```
INSERT INTO house (`id`, `string`)  
   VALUES ("' . $userid . '", "' . $new_home_entry . '") 
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `string` = VALUES(`string`)
```

Comment: I was too late and about to post the same thing :) Probably best solution in my opinion.